# What is the anatomy of a noname touch panel?

Tags: touch-panel

I would like to add touch support to my 17 inch monitor (the computer runs Ubuntu).

A quick DuckDuckGo shows some interesting results: http://cgi.ebay.com/17-inch-USB-Panel-Kit-Set-Add-Touch-Screen-Function-/160626649602?pt=Computer_Monitors&hash=item2566182a02

I am a total newbie in electronics and drivers, so here are my questions:

Does the installation of such a panel depends on:

- the display manufacturer?
- the operational system used in the computer and the presence of drivers for this kind of touch panel?

Is it difficult to DIY this enhancement overall?

Are those panels reliable?

Comment: As for reliability, it's a giant resistor. It's unlikely to fail. What could fail though are the bonding wires to the panel which would be next to impossible to repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch screen you link to is a resistive one, which isn't suitable for multitouch, so you get a single set of coordinates when pressed. It seems to have a USB interface. I presume it will come with a driver to install on your computer, or you might use it as a common HID (Human Interface Device). Either way it will work like a mouse or graphical tablet.

Comment: Yep. These show up as a drawing tablet, basically. It will work like a mouse with absolute positioning. Where you touch is where it will click.

Comment: That is ok with me, I don't need multitouch. I was really concerned if it will work in Linux.

Comment: @user5218 - Linux shouldn't be a problem. Drivers which come with non-standard HIDs (i.e. mouse nor keyboard) usually are for Windows/Mac/Linux.